# Solving a system of linear equations on the form $a^\top X \, b = c$

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, computer-vision

I'm implementing a computer vision algorithm for 3D point reconstruction from photos ([Tomasi-Kanade](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~yang/courses/cs294-6/papers/TomasiC_Shape%20and%20motion%20from%20image%20streams%20under%20orthography.pdf)). For the last day I've been stuck on a linear algebra problem. The system that I want to solve has $3m$ equations, with $m$ as the amount of photos, for which I want to solve for $L$:

$$a_{i1}^T L a_{i1} = 1$$

$$a_{i2}^T L a_{i2} = 1$$

$$a_{i1}^T L a_{i2} = 0$$

where $a_{ij}$ is a $3$-vector and $L = C C^T$ where $C$ is a $3 \times 3$ matrix. To solve it, it should be in the form of $Ax = b$. Had $a_{ij}$ been an invertible matrix, the equations could be rewritten as follows

$$a_{ij}^T L a_{ij} a_{ij}^{-1} = c a_{ij}^{-1} \rightarrow a_{ij}^T L = c a_{ij}^{-1}$$

but this can't be done since they are vectors.

I'm sure there is a simple step to solve this, but my linear algebra is a lot worse than it used to be and I just can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! It seems I misunderstood the definition of $a_{ij}$, it is a $2m$ by $n$ matrix, that clears it up

Comment: Ah yes, it's getting too late. I got it mixed up again, they are indeed $m$ by 3...

Comment: Are the right-hand sides of the equations always $0$ or $1$?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The idea is to eliminate affine ambiguity by adding two constraints: The image axis is perpendicular ($a_1 \cdot a_2 = 0$) and their scale should be one ($|a_i|^2 = 1$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$L$ can be written in detail as
$$
L = 
\begin{bmatrix} L_{11} & L_{12} & L_{13} \\
L_{12} & L_{22} & L_{23} \\
L_{13} & L_{23} & L_{33}
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
If $u = \begin{bmatrix} u_1 \\ u_2 \\ u_3 \end{bmatrix}$
then 
\begin{align}
u^T L u &= u_1^2 L_{11} + u_2^2 L_{22} + u_3^2 L_{33} + 2 u_1 u_2 L_{12} + 2 u_1 u_3 L_{13} + 2 u_2 u_3 L_{23} \\
&= \begin{bmatrix} u_1^2 & u_2^2 & u_3^2 & 2 u_1 u_2 & 2 u_1 u_3 & 2 u_2 u_3 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} L_{11} \\ L_{22} \\ L_{33} \\ L_{12} \\ L_{13} \\ L_{23} \end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}
This shows how to convert equations 1-3 to matrix notation.

Once you have computed $L$ (by finding a least squares solution to your system of equations), you can then get $C$ by computing the Cholesky factorization of $L$.

Comment: How does one ensure that the least-squares solution is positive semidefinite?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo That's a good question. I suppose I was just hoping that would happen automatically, since $L$ is overdetermined by the given equations. I'll have to think about a better way to handle that point.

Comment: I've tried using a normal and a non-negative least squares solver, but I am not getting a positive definite matrix. Most explanations of the algorithm (e.g. [1](https://classes.soe.ucsc.edu/cmpe264/Fall06/Lec10.pdf#page=7), [2](http://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~csip/sfm.pdf#page=4)) mention $C$ should be obtainable using Cholesky factorization, so I assume it should be positive definite automatically, not just semidefinite.

Comment: Are you getting a positive semidefinite matrix for $L$? If so, that might be fine. As long as $L$ is positive semidefinite it can be factored as $L=C C^T$.

Comment: I don't think so, the first eigenvalue is a large negative. I've uploaded my current implementation [here](https://gist.github.com/RvanderLaan/3d8821830f799b98471afbe755e535bd) with the contents of $L$ if that helps

Answer (score 1):

Given vectors $\mathrm a_1, \mathrm a_2, \dots, \mathrm a_n \in \mathbb R^3$ and scalars $b_1, b_2, \dots, b_n \in \{0,1\}$, we would like to solve the following system of $n$ linear equations in symmetric and positive semidefinite matrix $\mathrm X \in \mathbb R^{3 \times 3}$

$$\begin{aligned} \mathrm a_1^\top \mathrm X \,\mathrm a_1 &= b_1\\ \mathrm a_2^\top \mathrm X \,\mathrm a_2 &= b_2\\ &\vdots\\ \mathrm a_n^\top \mathrm X \,\mathrm a_n &= b_n\end{aligned}$$

One option would be to solve the following **least-squares** problem

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n \left( \mathrm a_k^\top \mathrm X \,\mathrm a_k - b_k \right)^2\\ \text{subject to} & \mathrm X \succeq \mathrm O_3\end{array}$$

Let us define

$$\mathrm A := \begin{bmatrix} — \left( \mathrm a_1 \otimes \mathrm a_1 \right)^\top —\\ — \left( \mathrm a_2 \otimes \mathrm a_2 \right)^\top —\\ \vdots\\ — \left( \mathrm a_n \otimes \mathrm a_n \right)^\top —\end{bmatrix} \qquad \qquad \mathrm b := \begin{bmatrix} b_1\\ b_2\\ \vdots\\ b_n\end{bmatrix}$$

where $\otimes$ is the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) (in NumPy: [`kron`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.kron.html)). Hence, the optimization problem above can be rewritten in the more succinct form

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \| \mathrm A \,\mbox{vec} (\mathrm X) - \mathrm b \|_2^2\\ \text{subject to} & \mathrm X \succeq \mathrm O_3\end{array}$$

where $\mbox{vec}$ is the [vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)) operator. In [CVXPY](http://www.cvxpy.org), given NumPy arrays `A` and `b`:

```
X = Semidef(3)

# create optimization problem
objective = Minimize( norm(A * vec(X) - b, 2) )
prob = Problem(objective, [])

# solve optimization problem
prob.solve()
```

Comment: Thanks, this approach feels a lot more intuitive! However the `Semidef` variable is not available in the latest CVXPY version, they use a `Variable((m, n), PSD=True)` in their examples, which results in `vec(X)` being of size 9 instead of 6. Adding `symmetric=True` does not work since it does not allow more than one  special attribute. Would you know how to define it in the right way?
I've also found an existing implementation that makes use of the `chainer` package [here](https://github.com/musyoku/tomasi-kanade-factorization/blob/master/tomasi_kanade.py) but your solution seems much clearer

Comment: @ThaRemo Thanks for letting me know that `Semidef` is obsolete. Have you tried `X = Variable(3,3)` and then making it symmetric and PSD via the constraints `X == X.T` and `X >> 0`, respectively?

Comment: I made a small error; setting `PSD=True` does work, as does adding those constraints. Is it a problem that all entries of $L$ are very small and that some are negative? And am I correct in computing $C$ from this $L=CC^T$ using [$LDL^T$ decomposition](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.linalg.ldl.html) since Cholensky only works for positive definite matrices?

Comment: @ThaRemo You can also compute an eigendecomposition of $L$ and then use only the positive eigenvalues and the corresponding eigenvectors. In NumPy, `linalg.eigh`.